# How to install Symfony 2.6 on Openshift?

Tags: symfony, openshift

I have tried the following [guide](http://hasin.me/2013/10/25/running-symfony-2-applications-in-openshift/) to install symfony2 on Openshift.
But It does not work. After I visit the /url/app_dev.php, I have got a blank page (yes I removed the IP checking) with 500 error code.

I have no idea what is the problem. I did this tutorial 3 times, and still does not work. However it seems the composer installation does not work too, because I've got this message after a git push:

> Could not open input file:
>   /var/lib/openshift/54a6c9f15973cac60f0000bd/app-root/data//composer.phar

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its a permission problem? Try chmod a+x on this file.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do it via SSH log yourself into remote server using the rhc ssh command. Then got to app-deployment -> current -> repo -> php and within this directory run

"curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php"

this is how you have composer.phar within your installed app